# Xcode - Hide multiple lines of code for later use

Tags: xcode, code-cleanup

I'm sure the question I'm having has visited us all sometimes.

Whenever I'm working on a project, I'll usually have a lot of functions that I'll write once, and never need to modify again. These build up, and sooner or later I'm plagued with a large list of functions that obstruct the part of the code I'm currently working on.

Now, Xcode has included some function to mitigate this, like condensing code like this:

```
-(void)func1 { [...] }

-(void)func2 { [...] }
```

and so on, to the point where you can condense the entire `@implementation` file:

```
@implementation MyClass [...]
```

But what I want to do is instead of looking at this:

```
-(void) importantFunction {
    //blah blah blah
}

-(void) uselessFunction1 { [...] }

-(void) uselessFunction2 { [...] }

-(void) uselessFunction3 { [...] }
```

where I could lose track of `importantFunction`, I want to be able to do something like this:

```
-(void) importantFunction {
    //blah blah blah
}

//useless functions
[...]
```

where `uselessFunction`s 1, 2, and 3 are contained in the `[...]`.

Does anyone know any way to do this? If so, I'm sure this would be a great help to all of us :).

Comment: So seems like no one knows...